# How to print sorted array after QuickSort

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I have written a Quick Sort algorithm which I believe is correct. I just want to print out the sorted array but I can't seem to figure it out. My algorithm is:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] myArray, int left, int right) {

    if(left < right) {
        int s = hoarePartition(myArray, left, right);
        quickSort(myArray, left, s-1);
        quickSort(myArray, s+1, right);
    }   


public static int hoarePartition(int[] myArray, int left, int right) {

    int p = myArray[left];
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    while(i < j) {
        while(myArray[i] < p) {
            i++;
        }
        while(myArray[j] > p) {
            j--;
        }
        int temp = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = myArray[j];
        myArray[j] = temp;
    }

    int temp = myArray[left];
    myArray[left] = myArray[j];
    myArray[j] = temp;
    return j;
}
```

The Partition is returning the correct result. My main looks like :

```
        int[] myArray= {3,2,1};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
        QuickSort(myArray, 0, myArray.length-1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

I am getting [3,2,1] and [3,2,1] as the output. I am looking for the sorted [1,2,3] as the second output. Am I completely missing something? I feel like this should be very easy...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the QuickSort implementation? I think you might have implemented it wrong (descending instead of ascending)

Comment: Seems the array is not sorted.

Comment: Seems your algorithm is not manipulating the original array

Comment: Did you change `A` in place, or created a new sorted array?

Comment: My first block of code is the quicksort

Comment: Then, `HoarePartition()`.

Comment: Also, please follow the java coding convention: (1) variables names (like your array), start with lower case letter (so it should be `a`, not `A`). (2) Method name start with lower case letter (so `quickSort()` instead of `QuickSort()`, and similarly for `HoarePartition()`)

Comment: I fixed, the naming convention, thanks. Is my quick sort implementation correct? And timrau what do you mean by HoarePartition()?

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in this piece of code:

```
while(i < j) {
    while(A[i] < p) {
        i++;
    }
    while(A[j] > p) {
        j--;
    }
    int temp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
}
```

Note that in the first iteration of the outer loop, you swap the first and last element, and get (as expected):

```
A = [3, 2, 1]
```

and `i,j` did not change in the first iteration.

But what happens in the 2nd iteration?

```
while (A[i] < p) { i++; }
```

This will terminate only when `i==2`, and `A[i] == 3`

Similarly, for

```
while(A[j] > p) { j--;  }
```

You will end up having `j == 0` and `A[j] = 1`

Now, you swap them - regardless of the fact that `j < i`

One quick fix is a sanity check that `i < j` BEFORE swapping the elements, because after the two loops on `i` and `j`, the outer loop property is no longer guaranteed to be true.

---

Also note, your code will run into infinite loop if the array can contain duplicate items, for example - try and sort the array `[5,1,5]` - it will endlessly swap the two `5`'s